# Is there a way to pass a fragment to graphiql?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphiql

It's possible to pass a query, but apparently not a fragment:

```
server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
    endpointURL: '/graphql',
    query: `# Welcome to GraphiQL

query PostsForAuthor {
  author(id: 1) {
    firstName
    posts {
      title
      votes
    }
  }
}`}));
```

---

**Update 10/12/2017**
It is possible to send fragments along with a query using Apollo's client:

http://dev.apollodata.com/core/fragments.html

This is not a solution to the original question, however; I would like to pass fragments to a graphiql server instance *at startup*.

Answer (score 1):

by *startup* do you mean from the server? if so I don't believe that's how fragments are used. my understanding is as follows:

1. on the server you provide Types (like `User`)
2. on the client you query those Types using queries and fragments

for instance, if you provide type `User` on the server, on the client graphQL you can use fragments to query that type:

#### graphQL (client)

```
fragment authorData on AuthorType{
  firstName
  posts {
    title
    votes
  }
}

query PostsForAuthor {
  author(id: 1) {
    ...authorData
  }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the OP, you'll see that there is a query: option passed to the server.  I can't seem to find this in the current documentation for apollo-server, however.

My question was: if query, why not a fragment?  The two are interrelated, so it seems logical to allow both.

Comment: i see what you mean. so yes in the server you can specify query and mutation but not fragments because: in the server you specify what queries the client can use, and in the client you are free to write those queries using 2 formats: query and fragment. maybe you say, "id like to reuse this particular query and dont want to rewrite it each time so ill make it into a fragment and use that" - the server doesnt care if its a query or fragment as it already did its job of specifying what can be queried (not how).

Comment: Queries aren't written in stone, either.  A fragment doesn't detract from the documentation of possible queries. One is not obligated to use a fragment,  just because it exists.

Comment: when you say "fragments exist" - do you mean on the server?

Comment: I mean in the initial query string that is passed to graphiql (not graphql), and shows up in the left pane.

Comment: and the example i suggested is not what you're talking about / doesn't work? ... let me update it to match your fields

Comment: btw theres no concept of "pre-population" in graphql client - what you query for is what you get

Comment: "btw theres no concept of "pre-population" in graphql client"   who's talking about that? Not me.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed (and as detailed [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql)) GraphiQL takes a `query` argument:

> query: an optional GraphQL string to use as the initial displayed query, if undefined is provided, the stored query or defaultQuery will be used.

If putting a fragment in as the value for that argument doesn't work, then I don't believe there is any way to start with a fragment ... but really why would you even  want to?  A fragment by itself isn't executable, and the whole idea is to start GraphiQL with a (executable) query.

If all you want is to be able to copy/paste in some text that you use frequently in your queries, a bookmarklet might be a better idea.

Comment: The thought was to pre-populate GraphQL with fragments to be used in later queries, no so much to execute immediately.